# Extra white-space and slashed double quotes when return from cfc angularJS

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfc

I am trying to preload some data using the angular-ui-router resolve method.  I am getting the data back from my cfc, but the data being return isn't in a correctly formatted JSON.

Here is the actual data, just junk data right now.  Also the white space preceding the json isn't showing up:

```
    "[{\"category_id\":1,\"name\":\"etsaaf\"},{\"category_id\":2,\"name\":\"test2\"},{\"category_id\":3,\"name\":\"test3\"},{\"category_id\":4,\"name\":\"testadsfa\"},{\"category_id\":5,\"name\":\"rob\"},{\"category_id\":6,\"name\":\"teadgafd\"},{\"category_id\":7,\"name\":\"asdfasd\"}]
```

I ran into the `\"` issue before, and it was setting the return type to json and using the `serializejson` method in the `cfreturn` call.  I'm not using either, but I am using the iknowkungfoo array collection cfc to properly format my json.

I fixed the issue, by `<cfreturn deserializeJSON(response)/>`.  Could someone shed some light on why they string was getting serialized twice?  But all the extra white space is still here.

[image]

Comment: Not related to AngularJS, I've removed the tag. The problem is clearly you're serializing an already serialized string, but I can't help you more, I don't know anything about ColdFusion.

Comment: Are you using a returnformat="json" in your CFC? I recently had a similar issue and this fixed it for me.

Comment: @ChrisWillard I have had that issue before as I mentioned above, but I'm not doing this time.

Comment: post your cfc, the url you're posting to, and check Application.cfc's onCFCRequest() (if any)

Comment: When you make the remote call from Angular, simply add `reurntformat=json` to the URL and simply return `response`. If you do not wish to do that, add `output="false"` to the function definition of the CFC definition and/or turn on whitespace management in Cf Administrator

Comment: @rob, just fyi you misspelled deserializeJSON. I edited your question